# How do you manage creation of a heavy and complex Information Architecture?

Tags: usability, navigation, design, information-architecture

Please share your techniques If you have ever been working on a design or redesign of a bigger website or an app that has a complex Information Architecture. While drafting it all manually (and updating frequently as the website is "alive" and changing constantly), the whole process is extremely time-consuming and dull. It also generates simple mistakes. It's easy to overlook small changes.

Is there any tool available that maps a site's structure automatically and display it in a visually satisfying and understandable way? (graphs)

Are you always drafting IA manually when investigating a product's structure?

I have tried scraping websites with tools for developers but the output lists still have to be converted into graphs manually.

Comment: Hi @moka, since this is a Q&A site, it will be great if you can reframe your question to be more specific. Your question seems opinion based. Some ways to improve the question would be - give an example of your IA - and describe some problems you run into etc.

Comment: Hi@harshikerfuffle I cannot share the IA as I cannot disclose the client's information. I am not sure what is unclear about my questions or problem description. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do a Heurisct Analyse from Jakob Nielsen:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

Mapping Erros, Do some usability test, talk with your users
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-testing-101/

See what your competitors are doing, make a benchmarking

Answer (score 0):

This might not strictly apply to your case since you are asking for the information architecture (IA) of a website and I am more concerned with IA and navigation architecture (NA) in apps to reflect workflows. But here is how I approach to visualise a process and conceptualise the NA accoding to it:

1. Visualise the most common user scenarios as a user journey map. I use diagrams.net for this.
2. Derive the structure from the user journey maps (in my case it is mostly sequential with digressions). [This](https://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/3-information-architecture/3-site-structure.html) provides a nice overview of the structure templates there are and for which scenarios they apply. At this stage tree testing already gives clues whether users find their ways in a complex information environment.
3. When testing document both a severity rating and a [failure mapping](https://uxplanet.org/ui-ux-design-mapping-complex-problems-7d48f1baffa6). In combination navigation or process issues become evident.

I would be glad if other folks posted their answers since the question (and exchange of solutions) is relevant for my work, too.